# AJAX jQuery CRUD with spring mvc without repeating RequestMethods

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc

i have a page with a form  and i have a AJAX function that returns a json with user details to fill some fields of that form and also in the same page i have a button to create a user from the information of that form

my problem is that to do this i have 3 controllers of the same page like this

this controllers returns the form with a GET method

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("forms")
public class myController {

@RequestMapping(value = "myForm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getPage (Model model) {


        return "forms/myForm";
    }
```

this controller is the one that gets me the some of the data in the form

```
RequestMapping(value = "myForm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String searchSomeFields(@RequestBody final String json, Model model) 
    throws IOException 
    {
         ObjectMapper mapper  =  new ObjectMapper();

         User objectMap  =  mapper.readValue(json, User.class);

        //get some data a fill some fields in the form 
         return toJsonInsertar(objectMap);
    }
```

and in this controller i do the insert

```
RequestMapping(value = "myForm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public @ResponseBody boolean insertUser(@RequestBody final String json, Model model) 
        throws IOException 
        {
             ObjectMapper mapper  =  new ObjectMapper();

             User objectMap  =  mapper.readValue(json, User.class);

            //insert the user with all the data in the form 
             return toJsonInsertar(objectMap);
        }
```

i try using two GET in the firts two controllers but i get a error saying that i already have a controller with the same  requestMethod and value, i try puting PUT in the third controller that does the insert and it worked, but i read that PUT is used to do EDITS.

how can i do this insert with what i have ?

Comment: Why are trying to map to the same url value for all get, post etc. Can you use different patterns, like getform, getuser and insertuser?

Comment: beacuse i'm doing the insert using AJAX, do you mean create a exact page with a diferent name? is that is the case i wouldn't have used AJAX in the firts place, i thin the problem is in the second controller i use that controller to return some information from the user to fill some fields of the form before i insert the user, if that controller is to bring info shouldn't be that controller use GET? i'm new in AJAX applications

Comment: Well, you don't have to create a new page. I assume you are triggering ajax based on event. So based on the insert or search event you fire request to different URLs of the controller. Does it make sense?

Comment: yes i have a serach button that triigers a search enevt using ajax that action calls my second controller this one `RequestMapping(value = "myForm", method = RequestMethod.POST)` this should be a POST method? are you talkin of using path variables to do this action like putting this in my controller value `value=myForm/{searchID}` ? and `@PathVariable searchID string` ? if that so in my javascript jQuery AJAX code should i use this url in the URL field like this `$.ajax({ URL:myForm/{searchID})`

Comment: if you can trigger a ajax call with URL like URL: /getuser and do either get or post with the required id. Then on controller side you can do @RequestMapping(value="/getuser") and do the required stuff. Similarly a different url for insert user.  This is becoming a long chain of comments. I am not sure how to open a chat, else we can talk on chat.